# Bind/Named named.conf deleted/replaced accidently.. recovery help

Tags: linux, centos, named

Apologies my bad english.

Well, I accidentally replace named.conf ..

is there any way to see the configuration again ...

named continues running without restart

show me something like configurations running ....

Thanks to all

PS. i tried to recover the file but it was not erased.

Comment: I think you need to repost this at http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a backup of some kind you're going to be out of luck.  Although you might get some vague details from rndc you'll never recover the actual file...

Answer (score 0):

You may grep your disk for it.

I usually add the same comment to all the configuration files i touch. Something like

```
## (pablo) /etc/inputrc
...
## eof
```

If i delete /etc/inputrc i can grep for it with:

```
fgrep -a -A 50 '## (pablo) /etc/inputrc' /dev/sda >/some/file/outside/dev/sda
```

You may use the same technique looking for something you know is in the file, like some domain name you were serving.

```
-a     force text search
-A 50  display 50 lines after the pattern matched
-B 50  display 50 lines before the pattern matched
```

-B is usefull if you don't know exactly where the pattern will match.